# javascript to jquery transition

Tags: jquery

I have a problem with jquery after converting javascript function to jquery

This is how my function looked alike in javascript code:

```
document.getElementById('checkoutForm').onsubmit = function () {
    var x = $("#checkbox-checkout").is(":checked");
    if (!x) {
        alert("Please indicate that you have read and agree to the Terms and Conditions");
        return false;
    }
};
```

**jQuery**

```
$("#checkoutForm").on("submit", function () {
    validateTerms();
});

validateTerms: function () {
var x = $("#checkbox-checkout").is(":checked");
if (!x) {
    alert("Please indicate that you have read and agree to the Terms and Conditions");
            return false;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div id="checkout-checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox-checkout">   
</div>
<form method="post" id="checkoutForm">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-green btn-pay">PAY nOW</button>       
</form>
```

do you know what could cause not even calling the function? Do you see anything wrong? What could be the correct way of doing this?

Comment: You don't have any element with `checkoutForm` id

Comment: When copying I accidentally deleted it but it is on form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below line has an error, in-appropriate use of object notation.

```
validateTerms: function () {
```

Option 1:

```
var validateTerms = function () {
    // to do rest
    // return true or false
};
```

Option 2:

```
$("#checkoutForm").on("submit", function () {
   var x = $("#checkbox-checkout").is(":checked");
   if (!x) {
       alert("Please indicate that you have read and agree to the Terms and Conditions");
       return false;
   }
});
```

Option 3:

```
function validateTerms () {
    // to do rest
    // return true or false
}
```

For Option 1 & 3, you need to use functions as below:

```
$("#checkoutForm").on("submit", validateTerms);
```

OR

```
$("#checkoutForm").on("submit", function() {
   return validateTerms();
});
```

Comment: but beware that in your Option 1 `validateTerms` will be `undefined` as you are using function literal, better go for `function validateTerms() {`

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#checkoutForm").on("submit", function () {
    return validateTerms();
});
```

Here you are calling a function `validateTerms();` to validate your form.
Now this function returns you `true` or `false` based on the validation.

So to decide weather form should be submitted or not you need to return true or false from the submit event.